# Creating new column according to the position of other column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, multiple-columns

For the following data set,

```
    mydat=data.frame(sl=c(1,3,8,10,4,6,5,7,2,9),x=c(50,42,15,49,56,30,66,52,40,38))
mydat
   sl  x
1   1 50
2   3 42
3   8 15
4  10 49
5   4 56
6   6 30
7   5 66
8   7 52
9   2 40
10  9 38
```

I would like to create another column according to the position of `sl`, The first value of the new column say `xval` should be `50`, second value is `40`, third value is `42`. So the new column should look like `xval=50,40,42,56,...,49`. 
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using `data.table`**

```
require(data.table); setDT(mydat)
mydat[, New := x[order(sl)]]
```

**Using `Base R`**

Contribution from Onyambu:

```
transform(mydat,New = x[order(sl)])
```

Alternatively:

```
mydat$New = mydat$x[order(mydat$sl)]
```

**Result**

```
> mydat
    sl  x New
 1:  1 50  50
 2:  3 42  40
 3:  8 15  42
 4: 10 49  56
 5:  4 56  66
 6:  6 30  30
 7:  5 66  52
 8:  7 52  15
 9:  2 40  38
10:  9 38  49
```

Comment: also add `transform(mydat,New = x[order(sl)])` from base R